# Handle relationships editing in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

We have an Angular app with an edit form for a model called Rule. This has fields for Name, Description and so on, which are all text inputs. Then there is a RuleType model which is a belongs-to relationship to the Rule model. We would like to implement this in the form a dropdown menu of RuleTypes when editing the Rule. These RuleTypes would be loaded from the database via AJAX (hence not hard coded in the Angular app).

The Rule model JSON returned from the API currently looks like the following. This can be changed if required

```
{
    "name": "TestRule",
    "description": "This is a rule",
    "ruleTypeId": 2,
    "ruleType": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Instant",
        "key": "INSTANT"
    }
}
```

The two ways I have thought about fetching the data for the dropdown is the following:

- Implement an API call to fetch all RuleTypes. Then map this to the dropdown and select the applicable one based off the "ruleTypeId" field on the Rule model

  - PROS: Is a generic approach that fits with the API design
  - CONS: Requires an extra HTTP request and manual logic to work out the selected item
- Return a list of all RuleTypes as part of the API call to fetch the Rules.

  - PROS: Requires only one API call
  - CONS: Adds extra data to the API call for fetching Rules. Doesn't fit well with the REST API design

What is the best practice/cleanest approach for fetching this data and mapping it to the models/view in Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this in a nice way by loading the RuleTypes via a separate Ajax request in the controller. This is then used to populate the dropdown using the ngOptions directive. The ngModel directive handles selecting the correct item based on ruleTypeId. This is then saved back using Ajax when the Rule model is saved.

This way didn't need any manual intervention apart from loading the dropdown data via Ajax.